# React Native Crashlytics Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

We are using firebase crashlytics in react native. But the problem is when the android app crashed, crashlytics give us android native code report. Not the react native code. That is obvious since it is already compiled to native code. But the thing is we are not able to map issues into react native code. Is there any mechanism to do this automatically or manually with the minimum human involvement?

Answer (score 2):

Crash Analytics won't give you detailed report in javascript. Rather it would define the screen where it crashed and the devices/OS etc. You will have to figure the crash yourself. It will give you the crash report like :

> com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java)
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.assertInitialized (SoLoader.java)
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.assertInitialized (SoLoader.java)
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.assertInitialized (SoLoader.java)
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit (ReactBridge.java)
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap. (NativeMap.java)
>   com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutorFactory.create
>   (JSCExecutorFactory.java)
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run
>   (ReactInstanceManager.java)

*You need to have a basic native knowledge or you can google these errors and know the root cause. Also, FYI *Sentry* can of great help to you as it records javascript error also. Also, A/c firebase latest version 6+ now records JS errors also*

Comment: It's interesting to know Crashlytics return such error as JS Crash. Would be great if you could share how this is a crash report from JS? I haven't seen any docs from Firebase regarding this. Thanks Rishav. Also, I would love to hear how you figure the crash with this context given.

Comment: You need to have a basic native knowledge or you can google these errors and know the root cause. Also, FYI *Sentry* can of great help to you as it records javascript error also. Also, A/c firebase latest version 6+ now records JS errors also. :)